# Auto Scrolling in Android Chat app with Recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am creating chat app through socket.io. Its working completely fine. Now What I want is when user enters text in edittext it should come to end position which I did through this method.

```
myRecylerView.smoothScrollToPosition(AbcChatBoxAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

I have kept this code on submit button of editext. Now every time the user clicks on this button although it comes to bottom of list but it shows scrolling from top to bottom. What I want is when user click the submit button the chat message should stick to bottom without scrolling just like in whatsapp.

Is there  a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int myMessageCount = mAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition =
                        mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
                // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
                // of the list to show the newly added message.
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (myMessageCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    mBinding.messageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });
```

mBinding.messageRecyclerView or mMessageRecyclerView (mMessageRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);)

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollToPosition instead of smoothScrollToPosition